# Why am I getting this error, when it cannot be true?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

This is the error I get in the Xcode Debugger.
[http://snapplr.com/ymrc http://snapplr.com/snap/21by](http://snapplr.com/snap/21by)
But look here:
[blah http://snapplr.com/snap/ymrc](http://snapplr.com/snap/ymrc)

How is this possible and how do i fix it?

EDIT:
[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/ffjr](http://snapplr.com/snap/ffjr)

Comment: what setting is the entity option under?? This question is a little unclear, more details would be great.

Comment: Added another pic. http://snapplr.com/ffjr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet it is because "group" is a reserved word.  Try a different name for your entity.

Comment: I never had this problem before, but I will give it a go.